# Delta Table saveAsTable giving null pointer exception

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I am getting the below error stack trace while creating a Delta table. Spark version 3.2.1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/spark-08dced9c-acdb-419d-8952-7d04e5531238/CitiBikeDataCleanser.py", line 60, in <module>
    readAndCleanse(spark, path, schemaName, tableName)
  File "/tmp/spark-08dced9c-acdb-419d-8952-7d04e5531238/CitiBikeDataCleanser.py", line 48, in readAndCleanse
    src_df.write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").options().saveAsTable(writeToSchema+"."+tableName)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 806, in saveAsTable
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o207.saveAsTable.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.DelegatingCatalogExtension.loadTable(DelegatingCatalogExtension.java:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog.loadTable(DeltaCatalog.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog.org$apache$spark$sql$delta$catalog$DeltaCatalog$$createDeltaTable(DeltaCatalog.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog$StagedDeltaTableV2.commitStagedChanges(DeltaCatalog.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.TableWriteExecHelper.$anonfun$writeToTable$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:484)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1532)
```

Code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder
    .appName("HOL Data Platform").getOrCreate()
    print("arguments", sys.argv)
    inputArgs = sys.argv
    if len(sys.argv) == 4:
        path = sys.argv[1]
        schemaName = sys.argv[2]
        tableName = sys.argv[3]
        print("Mount Path: " + path + " Schema: " + schemaName + " TableName: " + tableName)
        readAndCleanse(spark, path, schemaName, tableName)
    else:
        print("Pass correct argumemnts")

def readAndCleanse(spark, readFromMount, writeToSchema, tableName):
    ##Read File from bronze zone
    src_df = spark.read.options(delimiter=',').option("header",True).csv(readFromMount)
    
    ##Rename columns
    # schema for the raw trip history data
    trip_schema = StructType([
        StructField('tripduration', StringType()),
        StructField('start_time', StringType()),
        StructField('stop_time',  StringType()),
        StructField('start_station_id', StringType()),
        StructField('start_station_name', StringType()),
        StructField('start_station_latitude', StringType()),
        StructField('start_station_longitude', StringType()),
        StructField('end_station_id', StringType()),
        StructField('end_station_name', StringType()),
        StructField('end_station_latitude', StringType()),
        StructField('end_station_longitude', StringType()),
        StructField('bike_id', StringType()),
        StructField('user_type', StringType()),
        StructField('birth_year', StringType()),
        StructField('user_gender', StringType()),
        ])
    
    # read the raw trip history data to dataframe
    src_df = spark.read.csv(readFromMount,
                            header=True,
                            schema=trip_schema
                            )
    src_df = src_df.filter('(start_station_id Is Not Null) AND (start_time Is Not Null)') # remove any bad records
    
    print("Number of Records: ", src_df.count())
src_df.write.mode("overwrite").format("delta").options().saveAsTable(writeToSchema+"."+tableName)
    src_df.show()
```

As an work-around this fix worked

```
spark = SparkSession.builder
.config("spark.unsafe.sorter.spill.read.ahead.enabled", "false")
.appName("HOL Data Platform").getOrCreate()
```

Explicitly passing **spark.unsafe.sorter.spill.read.ahead.enabled to false**, fixes the error, can anyone guide me with the exact reason how is the config fixing the issue?

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/CDH-6-2-Spark-2-4-0-saveAsTable-error-java-io-IOException/td-p/297041

Comment: Thank you for your reply I am using OCI Dataflow (Oracle cloud)